# Why does Okun's law regress change in GDP on change in unemployment rate?

Tags: regression, econometrics, macroeconomics

Why does the Okun's law, the one that measures the relationship between unemployment rate and GDP, regress the percentage change in GDP on change in unemployment rate?

Why cannot we just simply regress GDP on unemployment rate?

What is the statistical difference between the two approaches?

Comment: The obvious answer is that level GDP is usually a unit root process, hence using it in a regression will lead to incorrect estimates.

Comment: Okun's law doesn't measure the relationship between unemployment rate and GDP, it models a relationship between changes in unemployment rate and changes in GDP.

Comment: but if the regression result has a very high R square reading, doesn't that mean the regression equation has done a good job mapping out the relationship between the two variables? why, in this case, does it matter whether the GDP series is stationary or not, (i sense this might be a very amateur question, if so, forgive my ignorance:)

Comment: High R square does not mean that the regression is good. Generate two independent random walks and regress them each on other. If you repeat this multiple times you'll get that R squared is high for a non-significant part of such regressions, when clearly no relationship is present.